# ffmpeg video segmentation for hls (m3u8) not displaying current time and duration

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm following the tutorial on http://www.bogotobogo.com/VideoStreaming/ffmpeg_http_live_streaming_hls.php

I can play the file on VLC. However, it doesn't show the current time neither the total video duration.

When I try to play it on safari using html5's , it gives me an error (on embedded quicktime)

How can I make it work on safari and show times?

I'm using ffpmeg 2.5.3 and the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -map 0 
-codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac 
-f ssegment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 
-segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 
out%03d.ts
```

Comment: Pleas post the exact version of ffmpeg you are using, and the exact command you are using. The more info you provide the better.

Comment: @YuriA.Brito can you find answer Yuri?